# Could not load file or assembly 'Launch, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified : Migration Error

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have been working on Entity framework recently i'm facing some challenging like when attempt to run the migration command it will show this Error

"Could not load file or assembly 'Launch, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified"

please if can help with i will be appreciated a lot

Comment: Posted twice: [Could not load file or assembly 'Launch, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575961/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-launch-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-null)

Answer (score 2):

in my case. I solved this error by correcting the spelling of my target project from where I was calling it in the extension of my services for the startup class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But please note that simple spelling errors really aren't too interesting as a universal answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case as well, the error was due to the project name being misspelt in my startup class within the ConfigureServices method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Constants.connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ProjectNameHereWasMisspelt")));
```